# Dinatural adjunctions

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question

Let $F\colon\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ and $U\colon\mathcal D\to\mathcal C$ be two functors. The traditional notion of "$F$ being a left adjoint of $U$" is expressed by the condition that there is a natural bijection
$$\frac{F(X)\to Y}{X\to U(Y)}.$$
I wonder if there's a notion of "adjoint functors" expressed by the condition
$$\frac{F(X)\to Y}{U(X)\to Y},$$
where the functors $F$ and $U$ are on the same side. Formally, one can define this notion of "adjoint functors" by the condition that there is a *dinatural* equivalence between $\hom_{\mathcal D}(F(-),-)$ and $\hom_{\mathcal C}(U(-),-)$.

**Questions:** Does this concept already exist? How much can be said about this notion of "adjoint functors" and how useful is it?

**Note:** I'm not talking about the condition of $F\colon\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal D$ being left adjoint to $U\colon\mathcal D\to\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}$, which can be expressed by the similar-looking natural bijection
$$\frac{F(X)\to Y\quad\text{ in }\quad\mathcal D}{U(Y)\to X\quad\text{ in }\quad\mathcal C}.$$

Comment: Where does $X$ live? You write $F(X)$ and $U(X)$, but this isn't well defined, because $F$ and $U$ take values in different categories.

Comment: Also, I don't know what a "dinatural equivalence" is, since dinatural transformations can't be composed with each other in general.

Comment: I would think that the proposed correspondence would make $U$ and $F$ isomorphic (let $Y$ be either of them).   What concrete example do you have in mind?